# AngularJs transition horizontal menu with ng-show

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

i try to make a horizontal Menu in AngularJs. I want to fade out the menu by clicking on a button. I want to realize the fade out by css3 transition but it don't work.

This is the actually code:

```
<div class="header-title" ng-bind="pageTitle">
</div>
<div class="content-container" ng-controller="AboutCtrl">
    <div class="navigation-container"  ng-show="checked">
        <li ui-route="/services" ng-class="{active:$uiRoute}" class="navigation-item"><a
                href="#/services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li ui-route="/services" ng-class="{active:$uiRoute}" class="navigation-item"><a
                href="#/services">Services 1</a>
        </li>
        <li ui-route="/services" ng-class="{active:$uiRoute}" class="navigation-item"><a
                href="#/services">Services 2</a>
        </li>
    </div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <button ng-init="checked=false" ng-click="checked=!checked" type="button" class="btn btn-navbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div>content</div>

</div>
```

Actually my CSS looks like this:

```css
.navigation-container{
max-height:600px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.header-title{
background-color: #dddddd;
padding: 15px 20px;
text-align: center;
color: #333333;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
}

.navigation-item{
list-style:none;
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
color: #777777;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1.4;
border-bottom:dotted 1px #dddddd;
}

.navigation-item > a {
padding: 15px;
display: block;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.navigation-item > a:hover{
background-color: #eeeeee;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

I want to fadeout the class "navigation-container" by clicking the button. Can anyone please help me to do the css for this?

Comment: `it don't work` is not a very good explanation. WHat did or didn't work? What steps have you tried to troubleshoot? Provide a demo in plunker or jsfiddle along with better explanation

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with AngularJS or even Javascript at all

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle the shows how to apply a style to an element based on a button click

http://jsfiddle.net/5vYzD/3/

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div class='box' ng-class='{"first": selected==1, "second": selected==2}'>Hello</div>

   <button ng-click='selected=1'>Apply first style</button>
   <button ng-click='selected=2'>Apply second style</button>
</div>
```